# Program does not print required characters

Tags: c

I am trying to print the rectangle. It works if i use the print statements but It does not print otherwise. If someone could guide me in the rite direction. Thanks for the help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


char * drawRectangle(unsigned int height, unsigned int width){
    int row, col;
    char *myArray = malloc(100);

    int i = 0;

    while(myArray[i] != '\0'){
        for(row = 0; row<height; row++){
            printf("\n");
            for(col = 0; col < width; col++){
                if( row ==0 || row == height-1 || col == 0 || col == width-1){
                    //printf("*");
                    myArray[i++] = "*";
                }
                else{
                    //printf(" ");
                    myArray[i++] = " ";
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return myArray;
}

int main() {
   char *c = drawRectangle(3,3);
   printf("%c", c);
   return (0);
}
```

here is link to the program

https://ideone.com/WxJuwx

Comment: Passing data with wrong type to `printf()` invokes *undefined behavior*. `%c` calls for `int`, not `char*`.

Comment: @MikeCAT, I tried that, it still does not print.

Comment: There is another undefined behavior: using value in buffer allocated via `malloc()` without assigning some value

Comment: Assigning pointer (converted from string literals, which are arrays) to element of `myArray`, which have type `char`, isn't good.

Comment: @Frankie_C, I  have attached a link to the program. I have made the suggested changes but it still does not print anything

Comment: This condition doesn't look correct `while(myArray[i] != '\0'){` . You allocate memory to `myArray` but still it wont be zeroed by `malloc`.

Comment: Please don't link to the code. Click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35648826/edit) under the question to update the code.

Comment: @kaylum. Fixed that, still no output

Comment: @ameyCU, I am not sure how to fix it

Comment: why don't you use a matrix? char **array

Comment: @reshad, trying to do it this way. Just wondering why it wont print.

Comment: Also don't assign string literal like this - `myArray[i++] = "*";` . You assign string literal to `char` ?? Use single quotes .

Comment: @Mani Because `calloc()` make contents of allocated memory zero, and the condition of `while` is that the first element of the array is not zero. For that reason, none of `printf()` in `drawRectangle()` are executed and zero-length string is passed to `printf()` in the `main()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward approach can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

void drawRectangle( unsigned int height, unsigned int width, char c )
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < width; j++ )
        {
            int blank =  i > 0 && i < height - 1 && j > 0 && j < width - 1; 
            printf( "%c",  blank ? ' ' : c );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    drawRectangle( 3, 3, '*' );
}
```

The program output is

```
***
* *
***
```

If you need to create a corresponding array(s) then the program can look like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char ** drawRectangle( unsigned int height, unsigned int width, char c )
{
    char **rectangle = malloc( height * sizeof( char * ) );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        rectangle[i] = malloc( width * sizeof( char ) );
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < width; j++ )
        {
            int blank =  i > 0 && i < height - 1 && j > 0 && j < width - 1; 
            rectangle[i][j] = blank ? ' ' : c;
        }
    }

    return rectangle;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    unsigned int n = 3;
    char **rectangle = drawRectangle( n, n, '*' );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( "%c", rectangle[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) free( rectangle[i] );
    free( rectangle );
}
```

Its output is the same as above

```
***
* *
***
```

Another approach is to create an array of strings that will (or will not) include the new line character.

Or to create one character array that will contain a string with embedded new line characters.

For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * drawRectangle( unsigned int height, unsigned int width, char c )
{
    char *rectangle = malloc( height * ( width + 1 ) + 1 );

    unsigned int k = 0;
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < width; j++ )
        {
            int blank =  i > 0 && i < height - 1 && j > 0 && j < width - 1; 
            rectangle[k++] = blank ? ' ' : c;
        }
        rectangle[k++] = '\n';
    }

    rectangle[k] = '\0';

    return rectangle;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    unsigned int n = 3;
    char *rectangle = drawRectangle( n, n, '*' );

    puts( rectangle );

    free( rectangle );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

- Remove useless and invoking undefined behavior loop.
- Use `%s`, not `%c`, to print string via `printf()`.
- Do not forget to `free()` what you allocate via `malloc()`.
- Check if `malloc()` was successful.
- Assign characters, not pointers, to `myArray`.
- Terminate the string created by adding a null character.

Corrected code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char * drawRectangle(unsigned int height, unsigned int width){
    unsigned int row, col;
    char *myArray = malloc(100); /* you should calculate the size of required buffer and use it here */

    int i = 0;

    if (myArray == NULL) return NULL;

    for(row = 0; row<height; row++){
        //printf("\n");
        myArray[i++] = '\n';
        for(col = 0; col < width; col++){
            if( row ==0 || row == height-1 || col == 0 || col == width-1){
                //printf("*");
                myArray[i++] = '*';
            }
            else{
                //printf(" ");
                myArray[i++] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    myArray[i] = '\0';
    return myArray;
}

int main(void) {
    char *c = drawRectangle(3,3);
    if (c != NULL) printf("%s", c);
    free(c);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I suggest moving `myArray[i++] = '\n';` after the inner loop.